# Airflow + Dask: task environment identification

Tags: python, airflow, dask

In the essence, I want to distribute Airflow DAGs with DaskExecutor, however, I have failed to find detailed information on how it actually works. Some of my tasks are supposed to save files and for such purposes, there is a network share accessible from each server running dask-worker. If my guess is correct, some tasks within one DAG could be executed on different servers with different paths to this share. The question is how to specify the path within a task depending on a worker and OS type executing it? If there is a better solution, or vision on this problem it will be great if you share it.

UPD:

1. Following the comment by @mdurant - the network share is a Redis server on the machine with Debian OS, therefore it represents as a directory on it, other nodes predominantly controlled by Windows Server, and share mounted as network driver.
2. For now the best appropriate solution I see, is to use the Dask framework directly from within each high-load task. As it guarantees distribution of computations among the cluster.

Comment: This is a bit of a general/opinion question. I hope someone has a specific example of how they do a thing like this, but you might want to give more information on how you set up your shares on each node.

Comment: Since it's not widely popular then there isn't much information about it. Consider using CeleryExecutor which is the most popular one.